# What is the name for a function that increases measures?

Tags: measure-theory

Let $(X,\mu)$ and $(Y,\nu)$ be measure spaces, and let $f\colon X\to Y$ be a measurable function.  Is there a standard name for the property that
$$
\nu\bigl(f(E)\bigr) \geq \mu(E)
$$
for every measurable set $E\subseteq X$?

Comment: I don't know any official name, but I would call it a "expansing function"